# python how to convert a very long data string to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to convert a very long string (like:'1,2,3,4,5,6...n' n=60M) to numpy.array.
I have tried to convert the string to a list, then use numpy.array() to convert the list to array.
But there is a problem that a lot of memory will be used(pls. let me know if you know why, `sys.getsizeof(list)` much less than memory used) when string convert to list.
I also have tried to use `numpy.fromstring()`. but it seems will spend a lot of time(wait a long time but still no result).
Is there any methods that can reduce memory used and more efficiently except sperate the string to a lot of pieces?

Comment: Are you trying to read from a file?

Comment: ANY method you use is going to have to split the string on commas and convert the pieces to integer.  I doubt you will find any mechanism better than `numpy.fromstring(sep=',')`.   If you're converting to floats, the result is going to occupy 480MB.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried `numpy.fromstring(string,dtype=int,sep=',')`,use memory:238.41867065429688M use time:775.8010931015015s. it spend too much time.

Comment: Have you tried using `numpy.fromfile` directly from the file, instead of reading the file into a memory?

Comment: Unfortunately,  it's not read from file, I receive the string from server.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string value and change it in your program, then the previous value will remain in a part of memory and the changed string will be placed in a new part of RAM.

As a result, the old values in RAM remain unused.

For this purpose, Garbage Collector is used and cleans your RAM from old, unused values But it will take time.

You can do this yourself.
You can use the gc module to see different generations of your objects
See this:

```
import gc
print(gc.get_threshold())
```

result:

```
(596, 2, 1)
```

In this example, we have 596 objects in our youngest generation, two objects in the next generation, and one object in the oldest generation.

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed this problem. But the question is if I only convert the string to list. 
`a='1,2,3,4,5.....'
b=a.split(',')`
the string use memory 231M, the list use memory 485M , but the memory used is more than 4G. I don't know why.

Comment: Because you did not enter your code, I said maybe this happened :)